# Цитирование в диалоге при переспрашивании, удивлении

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, цитата, диалог

— Наш сосед снизу сегодня съехал

1. — В смысле "съехал"?!
2. — В смысле съехал?!

Корректно ли оформление без кавычек?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **5.** Если в последующей реплике повторяются слова из предыдущей реплики, принадлежащей другому лицу, причем они воспринимаются как чужой текст, то эти слова выделяются кавычками:
> а) Купавина. *Ах, это смешно наконец. Зачем юристом, когда ничего нет.*
> Лыняев. *Как **«ничего»**?*
> Купавина. *Так, ничего, чистая бумага* (Остр.)...

Думаю, что диалог должен быть оформлен так (с кавычками; и не забываем про точку в конце первой реплики):
*— Наш сосед снизу сегодня съехал.

— В смысле "съехал"?!*

> — Это вы у Олега спросите, можно вам звонить или нельзя, это ваши с ним дела. А остальных в это впутывать не нужно, — сказал доктор твердо. — Вы сами-то хоть знаете, во что вы ввязались, раз вас с того света насильно вернули?
> **— В смысле «насильно»?** — слегка возмущенно поинтересовался Игорь, ему было странно слышать такой скепсис от человека, посвятившего себя медицине.
> А. Л. Сальников. Отдел

[Знаки препинания при диалоге](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=160#pp160)

P. S. О служебной единице "в смысле" можно прочитать в этой [статье](https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/sluzhebnaya-edinitsa-v-smysle-v-soyuznoy-funktsii/viewer).